# How can I format a drive to NTFS without an operating system?

Tags: windows-8.1, ntfs

I am trying to install Windows 8.1 onto a desktop I have that currently has Ubuntu. When I installed Ubuntu, the installer automatically reformatted the drive from NTFS to whatever format it was that it preferred. Now, the Windows installer can't automatically format the drive back to NTFS. I can't format the drive from within Ubuntu because, well, that's the drive the operating system is on.

How can I format the drive I want to install Windows onto to NTFS? Alternatively, how can I have the Windows installer automatically format to NTFS?

The error message the Windows Installer gives:

> Windows cannot be installed to this hard disk space. Windows must be installed to a partition formatted as NTFS.
>
> Windows cannot be installed to this hard disk space. The partition is of an unrecognized type.

Comment: First, delete the volume from within the Windows installer. Then select the empty disk as the install target. Windows will create a new volume and format it accordingly.

Comment: You can use diskpart a utility that exists within the installation environment, just delete the partition

Comment: @joequerty That does seem to be working. That was less than obvious, so you should put it into an answer for me :)

Comment: You can answer your own question if you want

Answer (score 2):

1. I myself had the same problem. It was showing the error because it's of format EXT4 where Ubuntu is installed, but you need NTFS.

   What you should do while installation is delete the partition which is showing the error.

   It would be mentioned as unallocated afterwards. Then select the drive and make partitions now as your wish. ;)
2. and about the first problem. there is way with the grub. I have no idea about that method. I know a method that may be really helpful, but sort of lengthy. Try to install Ubuntu again. when installing option comes, choose the options with something else (partitioning the drive).

   ii) a partition table will be generated. delete the partition where ubuntu is installed with the subtract(-)  button and quit installing.

   After that you will will come up with the second problem which you stated. I provided the solution above in 1st point.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a super old topic but just in case there migh be some people (like me) wondering what the solution is :
When you get to the windows installation screen, you have on the bottom left the repair button, click on it, then on the next screen, "troubleshoot" then "Command Prompt". Just enter the command "diskpart" and you should be able to format your disk to NFTS (with the command "format fs=ntfs quick")

Comment: Actually there's no need to format the partition whatsoever, if you have read the comments you'd know that. All can and should be done in GUI at the point where the Windows installer asks the user where to install. That same step allows for deleting partitions and that IS the ideal situation, a blank drive.